# How to create and use a multi-dimensional array in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

How do I create an array of multiple dimensions?

For example, I want an integer or double matrix, something like `double[][]` in Java.

I know for a fact that arrays changed in Scala 2.8 and that the old arrays are deprecated, but are there multiple ways to do it now and if yes, which is best?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Like so:

```
scala> Array.ofDim[Double](2, 2, 2)
res2: Array[Array[Array[Double]]] = Array(Array(Array(0.0, 0.0), Array(0.0, 0.0)), Array(Array(0.0, 0.0), Array(0.0, 0.0)))

scala> {val (x, y) = (2, 3); Array.tabulate(x, y)( (x, y) => x + y )}
res3: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2), Array(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Is `Array[Array[Int]]` equivalent to `int[][]` in Java? cause I heard vicious rumors otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090684

Answer (score 14):

It's deprecated. Companion object exports factory methods `ofDim`:

```
val cube = Array.ofDim[Float](8, 8, 8)
```

Answer (score -2):

How to create and use a multi-dimensional array in Scala?

var dd : Array[(Int, (Double, Double))] = Array((1,(0.0,0.0)))

Comment: An `Array` of nested tuples is **not** a multidimensional array.