# Array.isDefinedAt for n-dimensional arrays in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

Is there an elegant way to express

```
val a = Array.fill(2,10) {1}
def do_to_elt(i:Int,j:Int) {
    if (a.isDefinedAt(i) && a(i).isDefinedAt(j)) f(a(i)(j))
}
```

in scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you not use arrays of arrays for 2D arrays, for three main reasons.  First, it allows inconsistency: not all columns (or rows, take your pick) need to be the same size.  Second, it is inefficient--you have to follow two pointers instead of one.  Third, very few library functions exist that work transparently and usefully on arrays of arrays as 2D arrays.

Given these things, you should either use a library that supports 2D arrays, like [scalala](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala), or you should write your own.  If you do the latter, among other things, this problem magically goes away.

So in terms of elegance: no, there isn't a way.  But beyond that, the path you're starting on contains *lots* of inelegance; you would probably do best to step off of it quickly.

Comment: I was totally sure that scala compilers magically transform Array[Array] to a real 2D array, since it's supported by the standard library (`Array.fill(n,dim,array)`). What a bummer. Isn't there anything like a 2D array in the standard library? (Vector[Vector[_]] ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "real 2D array"? The JVM doesn't have built-in support for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @SethTisue - I assume a "real 2D array" is a M x N matrix, presumably one where the data is stored in row-major order flattened in memory, where the dimension is an indexing convention instead of separate data structures.  Alternatively, it could be an array of arrays where the dimension is typed to be identical (if you have a typed size parameter, which normal arrays don't).  The key property is that for `a(i)(j)`, what is in/out of bounds on index `j` does not depend on `i`.  (This is what a 2D array is in e.g. C++.)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check the array at index `i` with `isDefinedAt` if it exists:

```
def do_to_elt(i:Int, j:Int): Unit =
  if (a.isDefinedAt(i) && a(i).isDefinedAt(j)) f(a(i)(j))
```

*EDIT:* Missed that part about the elegant solution as I focused on the error in the code before your edit.

Concerning elegance: no, per se there is no way to express it in a more elegant way. Some might tell you to use the *pimp-my-library*-Pattern to make it look more elegant but in fact it does not in this case.

If your only use case is to execute a function with an element of a multidimensional array when the indices are valid then this code does that and you should use it. You could generalize the method by changing the signature of to take the function to apply to the element and maybe a value if the indices are invalid like this:

```
def do_to_elt[A](i: Int, j: Int)(f: Int => A, g: => A = ()) = 
  if (a.isDefinedAt(i) && a(i).isDefinedAt(j)) f(a(i)(j)) else g
```

but I would not change anything beyond this. This also does not look more elegant but widens your use case.

*(Also: If you are working with arrays you mostly do that for performance reasons and in that case it might even be better to not use `isDefinedAt` but perform validity checks based on the length of the arrays.)*

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. I was hoping for something more elegant.