# What exact class does Java use for arrays and how to instantiate it in Scala?

Tags: java, arrays, scala

I need to pass a 2-dimensional Java array of primitive values defined as

```
int myArray[][] = {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 }};
```

in Java terms into a Java library function from a Scala application.

How to define such an object in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent Scala to your Java is:

```
val myArray = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4), Array(5, 6), Array(7, 8))
```

Scala uses the exact same Array that Java does.  An Array in Scala appears to have additional functionality because arrays are implicitly wrapped by [WrappedArray](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html).

For much more, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381908/how-to-create-and-use-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-scala-2-8).

Comment: I couldn't believe this (sending Scala array of Scala objects to Java instead of Java array of primitive values) would work! But seems working :-)

Comment: @Ivan: currently, there are no such things as Scala Arrays ! Scala uses just Java arrays. Extra methods are added through implicit conversions.