# Scala 2 dimensional Array and Arrays

Tags: scala

I am trying to write my Java ode from in Scala and I think I need some help.
my problem:

Java:

```
public static int[][] ScoreMatrix = new int[5][20];
```

Scala:

```
var ScoreMatrix: Array[Array[Int]] = new Array[Array[Int]](5, 20)
```

It's not working, don't know why?

Error "too many arguments for constructor Array(_length:int)Array[Array[Int]]"

Comment: no its unfortunately not working ... type mismatch...

Comment: Ah, sorry. Probably this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381908

Comment: i cant manage it somehow i cant get it right !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For initializing 5*20 2D int array you can use:

```
var ScoreMatrix: Array[Array[Int]] = Array.ofDim[Int](5, 20)
```

Your code doesn't work because the Array constructor has only one argument, which is the array length.

Comment: some thing like that : var ScoreMatrix: Array[Array[Int]] = new Array.ofDim[Int](5, 20)

Comment: Yes but without the "new" since the brackets already call the apply method.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also

```
Array.tabulate(5,20)( (x,y) => 1)
```

which instantiates a 5 by 20 array with `Int: 1` (in general a function of `x` and `y`).