# Scala read multidimensional array line by line

Tags: scala

I am trying to read a multidimensional array line by line, as shown beneath:

```
var a = Array(MAX_N)(MAX_M)
for(i <- 1 to m) {
   a(i) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
}
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
error: value update is not a member of Int
```

So, how can I read the array line by line?

Comment: I'm not trying to be funny, but you're asking a lot of questions about _very_ basic parts of Scala. A quick run through one of the many Scala tutorials may well be a good investment of your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is actually in your first line of code.

`Array(MAX_N)(MAX_M)` doesn't mean what you think it means.

The first part, `Array(MAX_N)`, means "make an array of size 1 containing MAX_N", and then `(MAX_M)` means "return the MAX_M'th element of that array". So for example:

```
scala> Array(9)(0)
res1: Int = 9
```

To make a two-dimensional array, use `Array.ofDim`. See [How to create and use a multi-dimensional array in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381908/how-to-create-and-use-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-scala-2-8)

(There are more problems in your code after the first line. Perhaps someone else will point them out.)