# Scala create array of empty arrays

Tags: scala

I am trying to create an array where each element is an empty array.
I have tried this:

```
var result = Array.fill[Array[Int]](Array.empty[Int])
```

After looking here [How to create and use a multi-dimensional array in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381908/how-to-create-and-use-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-scala), I also tried this:

```
var result = Array.ofDim[Array[Int]](Array.empty[Int])
```

However, none of these work.

How can I create an array of empty arrays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misunderstanding `Array.ofDim` here. It creates a multidimensional array given the dimensions and the type of value to hold.

To create an array of 100 arrays, each of which is empty (0 elements) and would hold `Int`s, you need only to specify those dimensions as parameters to the `ofDim` function.

```
val result = Array.ofDim[Int](100, 0)
```

Comment: As an aside, I've turned `result` into a `val`, since I strongly doubt that it needs to be modified (this would involve *entirely replacing* the array of arrays, rather than just modifying the contents of a sub-array).

Answer (score 5):

`Array.fill` takes two params: The first is the length, the second the value to fill the array with, more precisely the second parameter is an element computation that will be invoked multiple times to obtain the array elements (Thanks to @alexey-romanov for pointing this out). However, in your case it results always in the same value, the empty array.

```
Array.fill[Array[Int]](length)(Array.empty)
```

Comment: Be careful: the second argument is _not_ a value, but a _calculation_ which produces a value and will be called for every element. The example given in documentation is `Array.fill(3){ math.random }` which gives 3 different random values.

Answer (score 1):

Consider also `Array.tabulate` as follows,

```
val result = Array.tabulate(100)(_ => Array[Int]())
```

where the lambda function is applied `100` times and for each it delivers an empty array.