# Chisel3 type mismatch with Array of FixedPoint

Tags: scala, chisel

In Scala one way we could declare an ArrayBuffer of array of Doubles,Long and Boolean is as such:

```
val A = new ArrayBuffer[Array[(Long, Array[Double], Array[Double], Double, Boolean)]]
```

I would like to do same in chisel.
In chisel I know one way of declaring a vector of length n as input  is as follows:

```
val X  = Input(Vec(n,FixedPoint(16.W, 8.BP)))
```

where n is Int, And this works .
Now I tried to initialise an array of n FixedPoint too, and did the following:

```
   val C = Array(Array.ofDim(FixedPoint(16.W, 8.BP)))(n,0)
```

Inspired from [initialisation of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863365/scala-create-array-of-empty-arrays/34870977#34870977)

But this did not work. 
I get the error

```
    type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.core.FixedPoint
[error]  required: Int
[error]    val tabHash1 = Array(Array.ofDim(FixedPoint(16.W, 8.BP)))(n,0)
```

Please, can someone give the correct way of declaring A above of FixedPoint, and an Array of FixedPoint numbers in chisel?
Thanks! for your attention and your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chisel will follow the ordinary rules of Scala collection declarations.
I am not sure what you are trying to create here but the parameters are not quite right 
Array.ofDim is for creating multi-dimensional arrays, so if you are trying to create a 2 dimensional array of FixedPoint you want.

```
val C = Array.ofDim[FixedPoint](m, n)
```

Where n and m are the sizes in the two dimensions. You have wrapped the Array.ofDim in another Array, so maybe you actually want a 3 dimensional array of 
FixedPoint, which would be

```
    val C = Array.ofDim[FixedPoint](k, m, n)
```

Both of these techniques will give arrays that have all the slots for FixePoint but they will not be filled in, so probably what you really want is

```
val C = Array.fill(k, m, n)(FixedPoint(16.W, 8.BP)
```

You can then wire these FixedPoints together how ever you want.

```
C(0, 0,0) := C(1, 1, 1) + C(2, 2, 2)
```

might be an example.

If you need to access your FixedPoint elements using hardware indexing you will need a Vec instead of an Array.  The easiest way to initialize Vec is with a Seq of Elements.  A 2 dimensional Vec of FixedPoint could be created with

```
val c = Vec(Seq.fill(n)(Vec(Seq.fill(m)(FixedPoint(16.W, 8.BP)))))
```

I would suggest looking at [Scala Land vs Chisel Land](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Scala-land-vs.-Chisel-land) for some background on using Chisel in Scala.